# GCP Dataflow Computation Graph and Job Execution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, computation-graph

Hi Everyone I tried hard to understand what is happening when I create a custom template in Google cloud Dataflow but failed to understand. Thanks to GCP documentations. Below is what I am achieving.

1. Read Data from Google cloud Bucket
2. Pre-Process it
3. Load Deeplearning models (1 GB each) and get the predictions
4. Dump the results in BigQuery.

I successfully created the template and I am able to execute the job. But I have following questions.

1. When I  execute the job, Everytime the models (5 models and each of 1GB) gets downloaded during execution **OR** the models are loaded and placed in the template (Execution Graph) and during execution it uses the loaded ones
2. If loading of the models happen only during the job execution, then does it not impact the execution time? Since it has to load GBs of Model files everytime the job is triggered?
3. Can multiple users trigger the same template at same time? Since I want to productionize it, I am not sure how this will handle multiple requests at same time?

Can anyone please share some information on it?

Sources I referred and failed to get the answer: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#pipeline-lifecycle-from-pipeline-code-to-dataflow-job [http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~wad/magiceight/isa/node3.html](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/%7Ewad/magiceight/isa/node3.html) https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/setting-pipeline-options#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-local-execution https://beam.apache.org/documentation/basics/ https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/ https://mehmandarov.com/apache-beam-pipeline-graph/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where the models are being loaded from. If they're loaded in the DoFns (most likely), then it will happen in the workers (during job execution).

As for your other question, there should be no issues with multiple users triggering a template job simultaneously.

Comment: Hi @robertwb Thank you so much. Yes the models are loaded in DoFns. Does loading the HUUGE model files stored in GCS impact the execution time? IS there any way to avoid it? like staging the model files?

Comment: You could possibly build custom containers that contain the models. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers

Comment: Hi @robertwb I tried using custom containers. Created docker image will the model files in it and tried to run the pipeline using the below command               python3 main.py --input=dsss --experiment=use_runner_v2 --sdk_container_image=$IMAGE_URI  But i get SDK harness sdk-0-0 disconnected. Error

Comment: This sounds like something easier to debug on the users@beam.apache.org list rather than here (though we could come back with the answer).